# How to convert a data table data into comma-separated list using lambda expression in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SiteName",typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CountryName",typeof(string));

dt.Rows.Add("ABC","India");
dt.Rows.Add("ABC","China");
dt.Rows.Add("DEF","Japan");
dt.Rows.Add("DEF","Pakistan");
dt.Rows.Add("DEF","Italy");
```

Required output

```
    SiteName        CountryName
    ---------------------------------------
    ABC             India,China
    DEF             Japan,Pakistan,Italy
    ---------------------------------------
```

Please help me to get the above out put using the lambda expression using C#.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: _using the lambda expression_ why?

Comment: For reporting but i know to work with sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following :

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("SiteName",typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("CountryName",typeof(string));

dt.Rows.Add("ABC","India");
dt.Rows.Add("ABC","China");
dt.Rows.Add("DEF","Japan");
dt.Rows.Add("DEF","Pakistan");
dt.Rows.Add("DEF","Italy");

var results = dt.AsEnumerable()
              .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("SiteName"))
              .Select(x => new { siteName = x.Key, countries = string.Join(",", x.Select(y => y.Field<string>("CountryName")))})
              .ToList();
```